# input field: limit the number of letters and numbers typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there a way to limit the number of letters and numbers allowed to type in to an input field? I would like to only allow 3 letters and 2 numbers to be typed in, in whatever order.

Is this possible using the [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)? Or not?

See my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0akoL2x2/

html:

```
<input type="text" class="preview" size="30" placeholder="Preview text" class="text-input" maxlength="5" autofocus />
```

jquery:

```
jQuery('.personalisation').mask("XXXZZ", {
        translation: {
            'X': {pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/},
            'Z': {pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/},
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, but seems like you'd need a regular expression that only matched five character combinations that consist of 3 letters and 2 numbers.

Comment: oh i see! can you point me in a direction where there is a similar example of this?

Comment: You could try searching on Google, but I don't know if you'd even find anything useful (seems like a pretty niche requirement). I've been trying to think of how I'd do it, but I can't really think of a better solution than to explicitly cover each of the various permutations: `/[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}[a-zA-Z]|.../`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a data attribute? Let's call it `data-temp`:

```
<input type="text" class="alnum" maxlength="5" data-temp="">
```

Use `$(document).on('input'...` to monitor all changes (even dynamic elements), and revert back immediately if the new value exceeds the maximum. Otherwise, let it happen, and update `data-temp` to this new value.

```
$(document).on('input', '.alnum', function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    if(
        txt.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length > 2 ||
        txt.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,"").length > 3 ||
        txt.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"").length != 0
      ){
        $(this).val( $(this).data('temp') );
        return;
    }
    $(this).data('temp', txt);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lphvezm/4/)

Comment: The fiddle allows me to enter any amount of special characters. I might be wrong, but from the post's sample code I understood that only alphanumerical characters were supposed to be allowed. Otherwise this is an elegant solution.

Comment: @igorshmigor You may be right, so I updated the if statement accordingly.

Comment: By the way, using a class and data attribute means you can use this on an unlimited amount of inputs; all the other answers will only work once per page as they either use global variables or IDs.

Comment: great! super simple! love it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/igorshmigor/k2ss62gg/3/

The JS code looks like this:

```
var numberCountLimit = 2;
var letterCountLimit = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.preview').keypress(function(key) {
     if (key.charCode == 0){
         return true; 
     }
     var current = $(this).val();
     var filtered = current.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi,'');
     $(this).val(filtered);
     var digits = filtered.replace(/[^0-9]/gmi,'');
     var alpha = filtered.replace(/[^a-z]/gmi,'');
     var digitCount = digits.length;
     var alphaCount = alpha.length;
     var isNumber = false;
     var isAlpha = false;
     if (key.charCode > 47 && key.charCode < 58){
         isNumber = true;
         if (digitCount >= numberCountLimit){
            return false; // too many digits
         }
     }
     if (key.charCode > 64 && key.charCode < 123){
         isAlpha = true;
         if (alphaCount >= letterCountLimit){
            return false; // too many letters
         }
     }
     if (!isAlpha && !isNumber){
         return false; 
     }
 });
});
```

P.S.: I don't think this can be done with just the jQuery Mask Plugin.

Comment: `.keypress()` can be unreliable. For instance, try inputting `11AAA` then select the text and try to change it to just `A`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you hook the keypress and check the number/letter counters and if it exceeds you will just ignore the keypress (by returning false)

```
var numberCount = 0;
var numberCountLimit = 2;
var letterCount = 0;
var letterCountLimit = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.personalisation').keypress(function(key) {
        var currentText = $(this).val();
        numberCount = 0;
        letterCount = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = currentText.length; i < len; i++) {
          if(currentText.charCodeAt(i) < 48 || currentText.charCodeAt(i) > 57) {
            //Is number
            if((numberCount+1) > numberCountLimit) {
              return false;
            }
            numberCount++;
          } else {
            //Is letter
            if((letterCount+1) > letterCountLimit) {
              return false;
            }
            letterCount++;
          }
        }

     return true;
 });
}
```

Comment: your solution works for the first 3 letter keys and first 2 number keys you press inside the textbox, however when you clear it out, you can no longer type any letters or numbers. other than that, seems like a valid solution, bulky, but valid

Comment: yeah this is pretty sweet, but once i clear the characters i'm unable to type it again

Comment: You are right, I changed the script so it will look trough the whole text each time

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. What happened when I tested it was that it let me type 4 digits and then nothing would work anymore. It also assumes that anything that's not a number is a letter, but that's not true, it could be anything.

Comment: I will have a look again at this later if no other solution will be posted

Answer (score 0):

Give your text box an ID.

```
$("#box").mask('XXXZZ', {'translation': {
         X: {pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/}, 
         Z: {pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/}                                       
     }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0akoL2x2/2/)

Comment: xenerr wanted it to work with any order though, not 3 letters first and 2 digits next.

Comment: The criteria seems to be length of five, three letters and two numbers *in any order*, so `NNLLL` is equally valid (where N denotes a digit 0-9 and L is a letter).

Comment: This will work only if I type 3 letters followed by 2 numbers, but the OP specified that he wants it to match in any order.